# Raspberry pi matrix multiplication

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, matrix-multiplication, raspberry-pi2

What matrix multiplication library would you recommend for Raspberry Pi 2?

I think about BLAS or NumPy, What do you think?

I'm wondering if there is an external hardware module for matrix multiplication available.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is off-topic. Read the rules what kind of questions to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica is part of the standard Raspbian distribution. It should be able to multiply matrices.